# ExpressJS res.download() on backend + fetch on frontend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

Sorry if it's a noob question but I'm not able to get it work...

I've got a backend which is using NodeJS & ExpressJs and delivering some static stuff built using VueJS.

I want to allow users to download files so I'm trying to implement it.

On the backend, here is the code

```
    app.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    let queryparams = req.query;
    if (queryparams.filename) {
        try {
            res.download(queryparams.filename); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Unable to read ' + queryparams.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.write('Unable to read ' + queryparams.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.status(501);

        }
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

On the frontend, I've tried to use downloadjs npm package this but it doesn't work and further more, do I need it ?

```
fetch(`https://${servername}/download?filename=` + data.filename)
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => downloadjs(blob, data.filename));
```

Any help would be appreciate

Bob

Comment: Could you print the content on blob ?

Comment: what is the console logging, what are the results of running the code?  what have you tried?   set breakpoints and log vars anywhere that seems reasonably suspect.  my guess,  console log all the crazy concat etc your sending to fetch, make sure that's legit..   then update your answer with what you have tried and the various results different scenarios have produced.  Please :)  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented download on my express application. When a user visits this particular URL, they will automatically download the file. It is a code snippet on a project I was working on. Hope it helps

```
router.get('/frontliners/file.csv', function (req, res) {
    controller.airtableFrontliners((output) => {
        res.status(200)
        const file = `${__dirname}/data.csv`; // Get the path of the file
        res.download(file); 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are missing is the path to the file you are trying to download.

```js
app.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.filename) {
        try {
            res.download(req.query.filename); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Unable to read ' + req.query.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.write('Unable to read ' + req.query.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.status(501);
        }
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

If we look at your code on the `res.download(queryparams.filename)` part, You are missing the relative path to the file (also the file extension type if you are not aware) that would be downloaded.

Suppose I hit this URL like: `http://.../download/day1.json`.
The code would interpret it as `res.download("day1.json")` right, but it wont know where to look for that file.

So if you change this to `res.download("./downloadables/day1.json")` the file `day1.json` will downloaded because the code can navigate to that file which is in the downloadable directory in the root directory of the code.
Making changes like the one given below can help you solve this.

```js
app.get('/download', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.filename) {
        try {
            // Adding ticks for string fomatting
            res.download(`./${req.query.filename}`); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Unable to read ' + queryparams.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.write('Unable to read ' + queryparams.filename + ' file. Please check');
            res.status(501);
        }
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```